# MacOS High Sierra 10.13 supplemental update not installing

Tags: macos, software-update, high-sierra, adobe

Since installing macOS 10.13.1 on a MacBook Pro (2.9GHz Intel Core i5) Adobe InDesign (CS3) has stopped working.  It only half opens. At the point when the software is loading and the running commentary flashes up "starting up panels" the process stops.  Some, but not all of the InDesign software is in place.  But there is no cursor and some of the panels are blank.  Fortunately the menu bar allows me to Quit.

I have tried installing the macOS High Sierra 10.13 supplemental update (supposing to address these problems, but half way through the installation an error page appears saying that the update "... can't be installed on this disc. This volume does not meet the requirements for this update."

Comment: *macOS High Sierra 10.13 supplemental update* requires macOS 10.13.0! If macOS High Sierra 10.13.1 (full or update) was installed previously it already includes the supplements and *supplemental update* isn't required/fails to install.

Answer (score 2):

Received wisdom seems to be that you need to reinstall the legacy Java v6... which until very recently had become unsupported in macOS.

In October, Apple finally made a version which would install on High Sierra - [Download Java for OS X 2017-001](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?)

You will possibly need to repeat this process after every System update.

There is an in-depth article on the subject, covering all versions back to CS3 far too long to even start to précis - [MacStrategy: Adobe Creative Suite CS and Java RE v6](https://www.macstrategy.com/article.php?135): Information about running Adobe Creative Suite CS on macOS with Adobe's Java Runtime Edition (RE) v6 requirements.

BTW, the supplemental update was to address issues with Adobe CC.
CS has been abandoned for years.